# For real estate investments, is there a standard recommendation for what to use for variables in the cash flow or NOI equation for rentals?

Tags: real-estate

I usually use a discount factor from rent at 5% for vacancy, 5-10% for maintenance and subtract capital expenditures or capEx as an itemized sinking fund that depends on the year and expected useful life of each item. Example:

`Rent*0.85 - PITI - capEx`

I'm asking in the context of myself as an investor analyzing and comparing various deals. I do not mean as a lender or related to buying new builds with warranties.

There seems to be quite a bit of variation among how investors calculate cash flow. Sometimes it's to feel like one bought a good deal when it was mediocre.

I would like to find some published material that recommends a bit more rigorous way instead of attaching various discount factor precents.

Maybe related to classifying the neighborhood between class B and C...

Comment: Do what represents the facts best for you. How anyone else classified the neighborhood doesn't mean much for your specific property.

Answer (score 1):

> When current lease agreements or market rents reported on Form 1007 or Form 1025 are used, the lender must calculate the rental income by multiplying the gross monthly rent(s) by 75%. (This is referred to as “Monthly Market Rent” on the Form 1007.) The remaining 25% of the gross rent will be absorbed by vacancy losses and ongoing maintenance expenses.

- [Fannie Mae Selling Guide Rental Income](https://selling-guide.fanniemae.com/Selling-Guide/Origination-thru-Closing/Subpart-B3-Underwriting-Borrowers/Chapter-B3-3-Income-Assessment/Section-B3-3-1-Employment-and-Other-Sources-of-Income/1032995141/B3-3-1-08-Rental-Income-05-04-2022.htm#:%7E:text=Lease%20Agreements%20or%20Form%201007,%E2%80%9D%20on%20the%20Form%201007)

So `rent*75% - PITI` could be used (from the reference). I think that's quite high; but when scaling, management would have to be hired anyway. That's about 15% burned up to management fees. From there, it's not unreasonable to take 10% for everyday maintenance, vacancy and capital expenditures.

Answer (score -1):

The way many professional investors do it is with capitalization rates, usually referred to as "cap rates". For a just-sold property with existing cash flows, you would calculate it as Net Operating Income (similar to how you calculated it above) divided by the property value (in this case, the sale price).

Naturally then, cap rates depend on location, which is how you can get different values for two different buildings with the same stream of cash flows, along with other things like zoning multi- vs. single tenant, custom/single-purpose use, etc. To give you a sense of the range, you might expect a 5-ish percent cap rate in Midtown Manhattan (at least pre-covid), whereas the one might expect to see something a bit hairy-er like 9-ish percent for a custom medical-grade industrial facility in, say, rural North Carolina.

Here's a short but decent [cap rates explainer](https://www.jpmorgan.com/insights/real-estate/commercial-term-lending/cap-rates-explained) from J.P. Morgan, which also has some reference ranges to help you benchmark your own discount rates.

Comment: Cap rate is used for commercial properties. It is a bird's eye view. It is simply the expenses over buying a property in cash (most of the denominator). Just mentioning them in general does not provide anything useful on the question posed (the numerator).

Comment: Fair point. NOI should probably be the numerator